# Android: IntentService starts but onHandleIntent is not executed

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I want an IntentService to run every 10 seconds and put a simply debug line. This is my code:

in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.test.test.TheService" />
```

Creating the alarm manager to call the service every 10 seconds

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    10000,
                    servicePendingIntent);
```

The service itself

```
public class TheService extends IntentService {

    public static int SERVICE_ID = 1;

    public TheService() {
        super("TheService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("service","I'm in on Handle Intent");
    }
}
```

In the emulator's monitor I see this line every 10 seconds

```
1270-1297/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x4 cmp=com.test.test/.TheService (has extras)} from pid -1
```

Despite the fact it writes "has extras", I actually didn't add any extras. Generally, It seems fine but the debug is never printed and a breakpoint on the debug code, never stops as if the service does start every 10 seconds but it does nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your logcat output filtered? Can you try to add a breakpoint and run a debug

Comment: it is not filtered. it is running in debug mode but it never stops in the break point on this line Log.d("service","I'm in on Handle Intent");

Comment: are you using `PedingIntent.getService` to generate the pending intent  ?

Comment: When I did, the whole thing was stuck, I then changed it to PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context... and it started to work except it is not getting inside onHandleIntent

Comment: What do you mean *it was stuck*? You *should* be using the getService() method

Comment: The application stopped responding until it told me to close. Changing it to getActivity made it at least show progress. In a way :)

Comment: Oh well, I now changed it back to getService and it started to work

Comment: you can't use getActivity with a Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an `Intent` to call your `Service`, and put it in `PendingIntent` with method `getService()`, as this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TheService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: I started with getService that stuck the app. I changed it to getActivity and it had the symptoms I described above. After a comment above stating the same as this answer, I changed it back to getService and it started to work

Comment: @Amos, cool, please accept if ti's useful